# Finding the last occupied cell using a formulae

Tags: excel

This formulae "works", but it seems a bit long winded. Can anyone suggest an "easier" formulae. It returns the value in the 5th Column to a date in the 1st column which is called from a separate (and discrete) worksheet. If there is no data in the 5th column (because we haven't reached or passed that date), then the latest available data is called ($A$20, is the "calling date, on a current worksheet):-

```
IF(VLOOKUP($A$20,'[FTSE100.xlsx]Meteor Step Down  
Plans'!$A$18:$E$2828,5)="",VLOOKUP(HLOOKUP(A20,'[FTSE100.xlsx]Meteor Step 
Down Plans'!$A$18:$A$2628,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK('[FTSE100.xlsx]Meteor 
Step Down Plans'!$E$18:$E$2828),0,0),0)-1),'[FTSE100.xlsx]Meteor Step Down 
Plans'!$A$18:$E$2828,5),VLOOKUP($A$20,'[FTSE100.xlsx]Meteor Step Down 
Plans'!$A$18:$E$2828,5))
```

The formula is in a different workbook to the data. The formula is used to determine the last value in an array, the first column of which is a date range (01/01/2000 to 31/12/2027....say) The required data is in column 5. Entries may be up to date (i.e. the last entry was made today, therefore it will pickup todays value. The last entry may have been several days (weeks) ago, therefore it will pick up the last value in the designated column (column 5). I don't see why it can't go into a named range, as the array size is fixed. Does that help?

Thanks Ron, nearly there. That works beautifully for "missing" dates in the array. i.e. when Saturday and Sunday dates are missing, it finds the value (in column 5) of the previous Friday. However (and there is usually a "however"), if $A$20 is a date in advance of the date of the last data in the array i.e. column 5 is blank at that date, your formulae returns 0 (zero), instead of the data as at the last date that data has been entered. i.e. enter 02/04/2018 and your formulae returns 0, not the data at the last date available 28/02/2018. Is that a little more clear?? (Thank you anyway, for spending the time - I'm still trying to work out how your formulae works as it does. Is the "/" significant (other than being a "divide by" symbol, if so it's something I've never come across before? Regards...........Mike. P.S. The dates in the array (Column 1) are all in from 2016 to 2027 (excluding weekend and bank holidays), and are arranged in ascending order i.e. from 01/01/2016 to 31/12/2027

Ron - Sorry mate, buy I can't see a "second" formulae???

Comment: A clearer explanation of what the formula is supposed to do is needed here, I think.

Comment: And is it a worksheet in the same workbook (FTSE100......) ? can this go into a named range to make the lookup arrays nice and compact for reading?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, (and that is hard to do since you give NO examples of your data, actual output or desired output), try:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((myDate>=A:A)*(LEN(A:A)>0)),E:E)
```

If it is the case that you have dates in column A and no entries in Column E, then you might have to do something like:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((myDate>=A:A)*(LEN(A:A)>0)*(LEN(E:E)>0)),E:E)
```

Of course, you will have to modify the cell references and named range to refer to the proper workbooks and cell.

Possibly something like:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(($A$20>='[FTSE100.xlsx]Meteor Step Down Plans'!$A$18:$E$2828)*(LEN('[FTSE100.xlsx]Meteor Step Down Plans'!$A$18:$E$2828)>0)),'[FTSE100.xlsx]Meteor Step Down Plans'!$E$18:$E$2828)
```

This should return the item from Column E that is either at or above the same row as `myDate` in Column A.  If `myDate` does not exist in column A, it will match the nearest earlier date in Column A and return from that row in Column E.

In the second version of the formula, it also checks that there is an entry in Column E matching the column A date, and, if not, it will look above.